# Drawing arcs with radius not at origin

Tags: tikz-pgf, arc

I'm looking for the best way (meaning simplest) to draw an arc for the interior angle of a triangle (or any other regular polygon).  I'm using a triangle presently.  Here's my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, minimum size=3cm,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3] (a) {};
\draw (a.corner 1) arc  (240:300:0.5cm)node[below]{$\alpha = 120\degree$};
%\draw (a.corner 1) -- node[right]{$h$} (a.south) node[below]{$b$};
\draw (0,0) circle (1.5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Regular Triangle; arcs inscribed}
\label{fgr:inscribedtri}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This is what it produces
[image: This is what it produces]

This is a bit closer to what I'm looking for.
[image: This is closer to what I want]

As a neophyte of tikz (and little more in LaTeX) I'm really in need of assistance).  Of course, I don't what the alpha there and alpha isn't equal to 120 degrees (that is a remnant of some past stuff that isn't what I wanted).  I want that arc that is terribly drawn in the top of the triangle with GIMP.  I want a node below it reading "alpha = 60 degrees".

As I mentioned, my attempt is above.  Is it simpler to place a vertex of the triangle at the origin and work it from there?  I don't really care.  Thanks.

Comment: If you have TikZ > v3.0.0 search for angles library in the manual

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define right starting point for `arc`.

**Edit:**
Starting point of `arc` lie on line `(a.corner 1) -- (a.corner 2)`, which cross `a.corner 1` with angle of 240 degree. In this direction on distance of 1.2 cm is starting point of arc. This is calculated in `($(a.corner 1)+(240:1.2)$)`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, calc, quotes, shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, minimum size=3cm,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3] (a) {};
\draw (0,0) circle (1.5cm);
%
\draw ($(a.corner 1)+(240:1.2)$) % arc start point
      arc (240:300:1.2)
      node[midway,below] {$\alpha = \SI{120}{\degree}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
  \hfil
\begin{tikzpicture}[% with library angles
   angle radius = 12mm,
my angle/.style = {draw,
                   angle eccentricity=1.3,
                   font=\large} % angle label position!
                        ]
\node (a) [draw, minimum size=3cm,
           regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3] {};
\draw (0,0) circle (1.5cm);
%
\coordinate (A) at (a.corner 1);
\coordinate (B) at (a.corner 2);
\coordinate (C) at (a.corner 3);
%
\path   pic [my angle, "$\alpha = \SI{120}{\degree}$"] {angle = B--A--C};

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Regular Triangle; arcs inscribed}
\label{fgr:inscribedtri}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** image on the right side is drawn by help of `tikz` library `angles` and `quotes`.

Comment: Thank you much.  Can you explain to me why, for the left triangle, the beginning coordinates for the arc are enclosed in '$' `\draw ($(a.corner 1)+(240:1.2)$)`?

Comment: As I said, you need to define starting point of `arc` it  lie on line (a.corner 1)  --  (a.corner 2)`, which cross `a.corner 1` at angle 240 degree. In this direction on distance 1.2 cm is starting point of starting point. This is calculated in `($(a.corner 1)+(240:1.2)$)`.

Comment: You need to pint @AndrewFalanga if the conversation involves more than one person other than the answerer. So I got pinged but AF won't have.

Comment: Good to know. For future.

Comment: @AndrewFalanga, for the case if you not notice my last comment: starting point of `arc` lie on line `(a.corner 1) -- (a.corner 2)`, which cross `a.corner 1` with angle of 240 degree. In this direction on distance 1.2 cm is starting point of `arc`. This is calculated in `($(a.corner 1)+(240:1.2)$)`. I will add this to the answer.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying: remember Tikz neophyte.  That makes sense to me and it's brilliant.  It does raise another question, since this is the starting point, why does the next parenthetical "address" say "start at 240 degrees:end at 300 degress:1.2cm radius"?  If the starting point is 240 degrees, why is it specified again?  I see that the Tikz manual I downloaded is woefully old: < 300 pages.

Comment: Some how you need to define starting point of `arc` :-). ZikZ developer decided, that the starting point lie on the circle, which  origin is for `radius` apart from this point and that in starting point the `arc` has `start angle` ...  Recent version of TikZ manual is 3.0.1a and has over 640 pages.